# usage of 'the' [the City Hall]/[City Hall]

Tags: grammar, definite-article

1. City hall
2. City Hall
3. the City hall
4. the City Hall
5. the city hall

I need to write about certain city hall, but I don't know which one is correct.

ex)

Only ***the City Hall*** and ***the Central Post Office*** manage to keep their places.

Comment: Your options 1 and 3 are capitalizations that just about never appear in English. A multi-word proper noun (if you capitalize "City Hall," this is what you're treating it as) generally uses title case, in which all words are capitalized except minor things like "of," "the," "and," etc.

Answer (score 3):

Under the vast majority of situations, you should say "City Hall:" both words capitalized, no *the.* The issue is that City Hall is the *name* of a specific building or institution.

> You can't fight City Hall.
>
> My apartment is three blocks from City Hall.

The cases where city hall should not be capitalized are where you're not talking about a specific building, but a member of the general class of city halls:

> The school had a crumbling Federalist facade, like the city hall of a mostly-abandoned farming hamlet.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is 4th option -

> "the City Hall"

In your example itself you have written it correctly.

Note:

It is based on my understanding and I tried to find reference but not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

1. General usage of article *the*: This varies by location... British speakers tend to drop "the", as in "Go to hospital." American speakers are more likely to say, "Go to the hospital."
2. Capitalization of "City Hall": If it is unique in this context, i.e. the *only* city hall under discussion, it would be considered a proper noun and would be *capitalized* and the article would not be required. Certainly, if the city were to be mentioned it would be capitalized, e.g. "London City Hall". On the other hand, if one were to write, "Norman Foster designed the city hall," then it would *not* be capitalized.